# Check every matrix element in matrix and put the result in a variable

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `v`:

```
0     1     0     0     1     1
1     0     1     1     0     0
0     1     0     1     0     0
0     1     1     0     0     1
1     0     0     0     0     0
1     0     0     1     0     0
```

I need to check every element in this matrix using a loop (if the element is 0 the result will 
be -1 and if the element is 1 the result will be 0). The result of every element will be in a variable to use it in another operation.

Comment: Subtract it with a matrix (of the same dimensions) containing ones on each element.

Comment: Are you **forced** to use a **loop**?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtract a matrix of ones of the same size as `v`, no need for a loop:

```
>> v = [0     1     0     0     1     1
 1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     1     0     0];

>> v - ones(size(v))

ans =

    -1     0    -1    -1     0     0
     0    -1     0     0    -1    -1
    -1     0    -1     0    -1    -1
    -1     0     0    -1    -1     0
     0    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
     0    -1    -1     0    -1    -1
```

or even just `v - 1`, as noted by @Andrey.

It seems @Veger got his comment in as I was writing this, so give their comment some love.

Comment: Or simply v-1  - it is a scalar

Comment: @Chris "their" = "his". I'm a grammar Nazi. My work here is done.

Answer (score 0):

Just try

[x,y]  = find(V==1)

to find the locations with value 1.